# Method doesn't work when I use ? after int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this Action method :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? mid)
    {
        IList<SubGroup> SubGroupLit = (mid != null) ? _subGroupService.GetAllWithGroupId(mid) : _subGroupService.GetAll();
        return View(SubGroupLit);
    }
```

I getting this ERROR:

> he best overloaded method match for 'ServiceLayer.Interfaces.ISubGroupService.GetAllWithGroupId(int)' has some invalid arguments

But when I remove the `?` after the `int` (in `Index` parameters), it works fine .

What is wrong?

Comment: `int` and `int?` are different types, similar but different, you cannot automatically cast from `int?` to `int` as system doesnt know what to do in case of `null`

Comment: you can change it as `_subGroupService.GetAllWithGroupId(mid.Value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `?` means it's nullable. Your `GetAllWithGroupId` method, however, only accepts `int`. If `mid` just happens to come through as `null`, then it can't be passed into that method because `null` is not an `int`. Hence the error. What you'll have to do is make `mid` just an `int`, which, as you noted already, works. Or you'll need to check `mid` has a value and then pass the value into the method. It looks like you were already attempting to do this with the ternary, but you made a few mistakes. The following code should work:

```
IList<SubGroup> SubGroupLit = mid.HasValue ? _subGroupService.GetAllWithGroupId(mid.Value) : _subGroupService.GetAll();
```